# Component render triggered, but DOM not updated

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-2017

I'm having problems with my first React application.
In practice, I have a hierarchy of components (I'm creating a multimedia film gallery) which, upon clicking on a tab (represented by the Movie component) must show the specific description of the single film (SingleMovieDetails).
The problem is that the DOM is updated only on the first click, then even if the SingleMovieDetails props change, the DOM remains locked on the first rendered movie.

Here's the code i wrote so far...

```
//Movie component
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Movie.module.scss";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Movie extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.imgUrl = `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/${this.props.movie.poster_path}`;
  }

  render(){
    if(!this.props.size)
    return <div onClick={this.props.callbackClick(this.props.movie.id)}
                name={this.props.movie.id}
                className={styles.movieDiv}
                style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.imgUrl})`}}></div>;
    return <div onClick={() => this.props.callbackClick(this.props.movie.id)}
                name={this.props.movie.id}
                className={styles.movieDivBig}
                style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.imgUrl})`}}></div>;
  }
}

Movie.propTypes = {
  movie: PropTypes.any,
  callbackClick: PropTypes.any
};
export default Movie;
```

SingleMovieDetails.js

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./SingleMovieDetails.module.scss";

import Movie from "../Movie";
import SingleMovieDescription from "../SingleMovieDescription";
import MovieCast from "../MovieCast";
import SingleMovieRatings from "../SingleMovieRatings";

class SingleMovieDetails extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = props;
    console.log('constructor', this.state.movie)
  }

  render(){
    console.log('SMD', this.state.movie)
    return (
        <>
          <div className={styles.container}>
            <div className={styles.flayer}>
               <Movie size={'big'} movie={this.state.movie}/>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.description}>
              <SingleMovieDescription movie={this.state.movie}/>
              <MovieCast></MovieCast>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.ratings}>
              <SingleMovieRatings />
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
    );
  }
}

export default SingleMovieDetails;
```

MovieCarousel.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Movie from "../Movie";
import styles from "./MovieCarousel.module.scss";
import SingleMovieDetails from "../SingleMovieDetails";

class MovieCarousel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = [];
    this.callbackClickMovie = this.callbackClickMovie.bind(this);
  }

  callbackClickMovie(id) {
    const singleMovieApi = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=b6f2e7712e00a84c50b1172d26c72fe9`;
    fetch(singleMovieApi)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ selected: data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    let details = null;
    if (this.state.selected) {
      details = <SingleMovieDetails movie={this.state.selected} />;
    }
    let counter = 6;
    let movies = this.props.movies.map(el => {
      let element = (
        <Movie movie={el} callbackClick={this.callbackClickMovie} />
      );
      counter--;
      if (counter >= 0) return element;
      return;
    });
    let content = (
      <>
        <h2 className={styles.carouselTitle}>{this.props.title}</h2>
        {movies}
        {details}
      </>
    );
    return content;
  }
}

MovieCarousel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.any
};
export default MovieCarousel;
```

I would be really grateful if someone could help me. I have been on it for two days but I can't really deal with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in `SingleMovieDetails` component, you are storing the props values in state and not updating the state on props change. `constructor` will not get called again so state will always have the initial values.

You have two options to solve the issue:

1. Directly use the props values instead of storing data in state (preferred way). Like this:

   ```
   class SingleMovieDetails extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
     }

     render() {
        return (
          <>
          <div className={styles.container}>
           <div className={styles.flayer}>
              <Movie size={'big'} movie={this.props.movie}/>
           </div>
           <div className={styles.description}>
             <SingleMovieDescription movie={this.props.movie}/>
             <MovieCast></MovieCast>
           </div>
           <div className={styles.ratings}>
             <SingleMovieRatings />
           </div>
         </div>
        </>
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops), and update the state value on props change.

Same issue with `Movie` component also, put this line in the render method, otherwise it will always show same image:

```
const imgUrl = `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/${this.props.movie.poster_path}`
```

And use this imgUrl variable.

Answer (score 3):

your Problem is just related to one file: SingleMovieDetails.js

Inside the **constructor** you´re setting the component state to get initialized with the props (send to the component the first time)

But inside your **render()** method you are referencing that **state** again:

```
<Movie size={'big'} movie={this.state.movie}/>
```

All in all thats not completely wrong, but you need to do one of two things:

1. Add a method to update your component state with the nextPropsReceived (Lifecycle Method was called: will receive props, if you are using the latest version you should use: getDerivedStateFromProps)
2. **preferred option**: you dont need a state for the movie component, so just use the props inside the render function  (this.props.movie)
   afterwards you can also delete the constructor, because there is nothing special inside. :)

**edit:**
So, just to be clear here: Since you´re only setting the state once (the constructor is not called on every lifecycle update) you will always only have the first value saved. Changing props from outside will just trigger render(), but wont start the constructor again ;D